# Cloudformation Certificate Failure

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have a cloudformation stack that's creating an ACM Certificate.  The code worked fine yesterday, and so I move it into being a nested stack.

The template is from a pretty nifty example.  I have a hosted zone, and that's where I'm requesting the certificate, and the template has a Lambda function which is supposed to look at the Cloudformation events, get the request for the magic DNS entry, and write that DNS entry into the hosted zone to effect DNS validation of the cert request.

The Lambda instances, gets the info from CF, and writes it to the hosted zone.  Everything it's supposed to have done (and did fine yesterday) has happened.

And it's not even *timing out*.  The error I get is:

```
Waiter StackCreateComplete failed: Max attempts exceeded
```

Any ideas?  I've seen AWS take it's sweet time marking certs as good doing this by hand in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Upon closer examination it became clear that this message was from the boto3 client, not AWS, and that the default timeout for the client was the same as on the template.

Modifying the template timeout to 12 hours and rerunning the command still results in that message being generated, but the GUI shows that it's still running.